# SwiftUI Error: Update NavigationAuthority bound path tried to update multiple times per frame

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am getting the following debug message:

> "Update NavigationAuthority bound path tried to update multiple times
> per frame."

Does anyone know how to resolve the output message?

I can't find anything online about how to resolve this message, and it only started appearing when I added the following NavigationLink:

```
var body: some View {
    getViewFor(state: viewmodel.state)
        .navigationTitle("NYC schools")
        .toolbar{
            NavigationLink("Settings") {
                SettingsView()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Without a [mre], it's probably not possible to solve this. This likely depends on `getViewFor(state:)`, which you haven't included.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74433636/

Answer (score 16):

This message occurs, when you use a path-variable which is an ObservableObject (@Published) or @Observable (iOS17).

For example:

`NavigationStack(path: self.navigationPathModel.$mainMenuNavPath)`

Either you live with the NavigationAuthority message, or you should change your View concept to @State variables, because they do not produce the message.

From iOS16.4 on the the message "**NavigationRequestObserver** tried to update multiple times per frame" at least got fixed.

But the "**NavigationAuthority**..." message is still present in iOS17.1 / Xcode 15.0.1.

Comment: Can confirm this is accurate as of iOS 17 / Xcode 15.0.1 i.e. the "NavigationAuthority..." message is still present, but the "NavigationRequestObserver" one is gone.

Comment: @Kuhlemann should one resolve the message/error in iOS17 by reverting back to Published or can it be ignored?

Comment: @Peanutsmasher It can be ignored if you do not have any performance issues in your app.

Comment: This can not be ignored, because after getting this warning. We can't present sheets further. It stopped working for Sheets.

Comment: In my case next navigations stopped working after getting this warning. It started working if we provide unique id to every path appended element. By unique i mean don't use UUID() instead assign a fix/unique value to every appended element

Comment: Hi @AabanTariqMurtaza, same for me also happening next navigation is freezing with NavigationAuthority message. How we provide unique id to every path appended element? Could you please explain more this?

Answer (score 1):

this might be due to navigation destinations with data dependencies captured from ancestor views, like:

```swift
struct DataDependentNavigation: View {
  @State var changeColor: Bool = false
  @State var present: Bool = false


  var body: some View {
  NavigationSplitView {
    Color.blue
      .navigationDestination(isPresented: $present) {
           // This is a data dependency from an ancestor view
            changeColor ? Color.green : Color.yellow
      }
  } detail: {
    Color.teal
  }
}
```

[it seems like it was fixed/improved on iOS 16.4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-16_4-release-notes#SwiftUI-Navigation), but I'm still seeing this on iOS 17